# Dell Latitude E7270

Tags: system-installation

I can buy Dell Latitude E7270 through my employer. It will come with Windows, but I would like to install Ubuntu (most likely 14.04). This model does not appear on the list of certified hardware, however. Does anyone know whether I should anticipate any problems with his laptop? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It will support see the [spec sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/NA-Latitude-7000-Series-E7x70-Spec-Sheet.pdf).
There is Ubuntu 14.04 in the supported OSes.

Comment: I've edited as I think this is a legitimate answer.