# Will Ubuntu work on this laptop - Dell E7270?

Tags: support

Here is a link to the product:

https://www.pcworldbusiness.co.uk/catalogue/item/P236767P

Comment: Please check this thread which is covering the same topic for the same Dell 7270 -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/804378/dell-latitude-e7270

Answer (score 1):

According to its spec [sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/NA-Latitude-7000-Series-E7x70-Spec-Sheet.pdf), Ubuntu 14.04 LTS works well on Dell Latitude E7270 .

Here is a [link](http://www.techmagnifier.com/laptop/dell-latitude-7000-series-e7270e7470-price-and-specifications) where you can see (some of) the OSs supported by this laptop:

- Windows 7, 8.1 Pro ,10 32/64bit
- Ubuntu Linux 14.04
- NeoKylin v6.0